# Plugin connection to MySQL error

Tags: mysql

I have installed aplugin to server but there seems to be issue. Any idea?

File "/usr/local/mysqlplugin/MySQLPro.py", line 401, in _getData

self.agentConfig['MySQLPass']

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect

return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in **init**

super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)

OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")

Comment: The error message is quite clear. The script can't connect to your MySQL server. Is the MySQL server running and reachable via 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Changing from 127.0.0.1 to localhost worked. thanks